# Expiration of Persistent data in gemfire

Tags: persistent, diskspace, ttl, gemfire

When a persistent entry in gemfire expires, is the disk space used by the expired entry immediately available for reuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly. It's immediately marked as garbage. Gemfire always appends updates to the most recent oplog files. Old oplog files will be compacted when they are 50% garbage (by default). So your expired entry will be considered garbage in the old oplog, and that space will be reclaimed when that oplog reaches 50% garbage and gets compacted.

Comment: Is the expiration action then just a delete entry in the oplog?